# what is best way to redirect all request to login page in servlet

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I am new to tomcat and servlet. 
here is the situation, I am trying to redirect user all url(direct url) to login page to force user log in.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to write an interceptor ([read this](http://tomcatbook.sourceforge.net/book/defaulthtml/ch04.html)) which is basically a java object that gets invoked on each request and can do some processing like redirecting to a login page in the absence of a predefined cookie.

Comment: so in the filter class, what should I check? i mean in term of request session? or what? otherwise how do we know if user is logged on or not?

Comment: Like I said, I would typically check for the existence of an authentication cookie. If it is not there of if it is expired you just redirect to your login page.

Comment: i tried just now, i did not work somehow, do i have to have some sort of ini parameter?

Comment: ok i found whats wrong, it seems filter is applied to every single request, so when redirecting to login.jsp, filter is run again and then redirect to login.jsp again, it becomes a loop. any idea how to except login.jsp from filter?? ( i ran session check in filter)

Comment: Just check the url in the filter to do nothing when you see login.jsp. Remember that your login.jsp will need to create the cookie so that the next requests go through. At the end of the login, you could redirect back to the original referer

Comment: what do you mean by having to create cookie on login.jsp? why do we need cookie in this case?

Comment: Well, once you've entered (and validated) your credentials in login.jsp, you'll need something that tells your interceptor that the user is authenticated. The best way to do that is to have login.jsp set a cookie (with some encrypted signature if you're serious about security). At this point, your interceptor can check for the presence and the validity of the cookie which should be present in every request. If you've got a logout function, all it needs to do is to clear the cookie

Comment: thank for the clarification, now, i have filter up and running, and i can see it redirects to login.jsp, but after redirection, the webpage is just blank, even manually access login.jsp, any idea?

Comment: Does your login.jsp have a jsp:include? If so, loading that page will also trigger your interceptor